Error in eval(y, envir = model$data, enclos = model$specials) : object 'Delays' not found
This is my first post, excuse any mistakes.
This is a block of code for r I wrote.
train_set_tsibble <- as_tsibble(train_set, index = date, key = Delays)

train_set_tsibble <- train_set_tsibble %>%
    arrange(date)

train_set$Delays <- as.numeric(train_set$Delays)


fit2 <- train_set_tsibble %>%
    model(
        ets = ETS(box_cox(Delays, 0.3)),
        arima = ARIMA(Delays ~ PDQ(0,1,1) + pdq(0,1,1)),
        snaive = SNAIVE(Delays)
  )
fit2

Basically when it tries to do the model bit at the end it gives me the error in the title, Delays is not found. I'm not really sure what is wrong, I had a different set of data based on the built in AirPassengers and the model worked fine for it. I thought the problem might be the class but it still gives me the error.
Before I made Delays numeric it was integer
Train_set was a tibble_df
here is the bigger error message:
Error in eval(y, envir = model$data, enclos = model$specials) : 
  object 'Delays' not found

I tried changing classes and I looked over the data, when i call train_set_tsibble$delays i get numbers

train_set$Delays <- as.numeric(train_set$Delays) ==> train_set_tsibble$Delays <- as.numeric(train_set_tsibble$Delays)

I added that change, but I still get the same error unfortunately
